# Copy/paste values from sheet to sheet if column headings not matched (but using Mapping of the headers in separate sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I have Input that contains a Mapping Sheet to Match different Headers
Ex:

```
    Mapping Sheet
     +------+------------+------+
    |header 1  |    header 2    |
     +------+------------+------+
    |sam_name  |    sam.value   |
    |John_name |    John.value  | 
    |Car_name  |  Car.value     |
     +------+------------+------+
```

I have another two sheets say Source and Target sheet.
- Source sheet has header2 values as Headers in Column2 (ex: sam.value, John.value, etc.)
- Target sheet headers has header1 values as headers in Column1 (ex: sam_name, John_name, etc.)

I need to copy paste the values from Source sheet headers to Target sheet under Column2 by mapping the correct respective headers from mapping sheet.

Below are the codes I worked on.

```vb
Set sc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("conf_sheet") 'Contains Mapping of headers of source and Target sheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source_sheet")
Set scrsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target_sheet")

wrow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
wcol = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
srow = sc.UsedRange.Rows.Count
scol = sc.UsedRange.Columns.Count

counter = 0
cnt = 0

For i = 2 To srow
    For j = 1 To wcol

        If InStr(1, UCase(ws1.Cells(sc.Cells(i, 4).Value, j).Value), UCase(sc.Cells(i, 1).Value), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            Range(scrsh.Cells(2, counter + 1), scrsh.Cells(wrow, counter + 1)).Value = Range(ws1.Cells(3, j), ws1.Cells(wrow, j)).Value
            counter = counter + 1

        End If
        End If
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next j
 Next i
```

Comment: What have you done thusfar to support this macro?  Please provide any code you've generated (working or not) so we can help fix errors, issues.  If you need help getting started, give the *Macro Recorder* a shot, in the Developer ribbon of Excel.  For further research, look into `Looping`, in additon to general `.Copy` and `.Paste` if not `Destination.Value = Source.Value`.

Comment: Hi Cyril, I have re-shared my codes above, It would be great if you can help me with the looping part

Comment: What type of values are in `Sheets("conf_sheet")`?  Just numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that I am understanding this correctly.

- You have one destination sheet (Target) and one source sheet (Source).
- You are focused on the label in `cells(i,1)` on the destination sheet.
- You want to match all source sheet `cells(j,1)` with destination sheet `cells(i,1)`
- If you have the match, then you append the source data in `cells(j,2)` to the last column of the destination sheet on `rows(i)`

---

Based on those understandings, I would make a couple changes/suggestions to your code:

- Change the sheet name references to be representative of what is going on (e.g., "s" in srow, etc., makes me think this is the source sheet)
- `UsedRange` may be unreliable, so take a look at finding the last row/last column based on some rows/columns that will always have data
- Indent your code so it is more readable

---

Here is my shot with mocking up some code, in reflection of the above understandings (Not tested due to lack of understanding of "conf_sheet"):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim Conf As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet, dstWS As Worksheet
    Dim srcRowCt As Long, srcColCt As Long, dstRowCt As Long, dstColCt As Long
    Dim dstLastCol As Long, ValCheck As String
    Set Conf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("conf_sheet") 'Contains Mapping of headers of source and Target sheet
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source_sheet")
    Set dstWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target_sheet")
    srcRowCt = srcWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    srcColCt = srcWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ConfRowCt = Conf.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ConfColCt = Conf.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    'removed "counter": you're pasting one beyond the last column, so can just find that
    'removed "cnt": this didn't appear to be used at all
    With srcWS
        For i = 2 To ConfRowCt
            ValCheck = UCase(dstWS.Cells(i, 1).Value) 'Makes this check one time outside the other loop so you speed things up
            For j = 1 To srcColCt
                If InStr(1, UCase(.Cells(Conf.Cells(i, 4).Value, j).Value), ValCheck, vbTextCompare) Then
                    dstLastCol = dstWS.Cells(j, dstWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'determins last column dynamically; could also just move the "counter" you previously had up here, so you don't need +1 in your other formula
                    dstWS.Cells(1, dstLastCol + 1).Value = ValCheck 'Added in a header to column so the dstLastCol will have somethign to work with AND so you remember what was checked
                    dstWS.Range(dstWS.Cells(2, dstLastCol + 1), dstWS.Cells(wrow, dstLastCol + 1)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, j), .Cells(srcRowCt, j)).Value 'changed source range to equal the dest range (2:srcRowCt), you had (3:srcRowCt) for source
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

One thing that wwasn't easily typable due to other comments:  when you qualify a range, qualify all aspects.  You had `Range(ws.Cells(...))` but should always be `ws.Range(ws.Cells(...))` to fully qualify.  If you don't fully qualify then wherever `Range` shows up will take the activesheet, which can lead to errors.

Comment: Hi Cyril, Thank you so much for your help your above codes are very useful i have got an idea to complete my macro. Again Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @sharathkumar if this answered your question, please mark as answered so this does not show up needing attention in the "open questions" field.